# How to reference custom Python files when training a model with tensorflow_cloud in GCP?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to train a Tensorflow model in Google Cloud using tensorflow_cloud.

So I have the following code triggering the training:

```
import tensorflow_cloud as tfc
tfc.run(
    requirements_txt="requirements.txt",
    distribution_strategy="auto",
    docker_image_bucket_name=<bucket-name>
)
```

I have a simple python file with some util functions let's say its' name is `utils.py`

So, in the notebook I'm importing this file like so:

`from utils import *`

My question is - How do I reference this file when running the notebook in GCP?

At the moment I get a module not found error indicating the utils file can't be found.

I'm trying to copy the file to my GCP bucket but it still says it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to use `import` to import and access functions, which you have in a separate `.py` file. The error you received happened because the interpreter could not find your package (`.py`) in the current or gobal directories. For this reason, you need to add the proper path and import the module.

In order to access them without an error, you need to follow the steps below,

1. Create a folder within your Jupyter notebook by clicking in the **New Folder** button;
2. Upload the `.py` file there;
3. You need to add path to the file which is located in the new directory you created in the first step. Now, in the `.ipynb` you want to import the file, execute

```
    import sys  
    sys.path.insert(0,"your_path/package")
    import your_file as pck
```

*Note: replace the proper fields with your file path and file name*

It will be imported successfully. Then you will be able to use the functions within the file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer my question. You're describing the scenario when working with a Jupyter notebook locally or in Google Colab for example. My problem is that I want to run the code from the notebook in GCP. As far as I know, tensorflow cloud will package the code and all dependencies to a docker image. When doing so, it should somehow copy my utils.py file. But I don't know when to upload this file in the first place so it's accessible by the GCP build.
Reference for training models on GCP - https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/08/train-your-tensorflow-model-on-google.html

Comment: I have used the Notebook provided by [AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/introduction) in GCP. Could you please tell me more about what your goal is?

Comment: My final goal is to train a model on GCP. I just have a few helper functions in a separate file that I want to reference. And the problem is this file is missing when the docker image is being created by the GCP build. Probably I need to instruct GCP to copy all the contents of the current directory (which contains the utils file) to the docker image. It should be super simple but I've been struggling for a while now.

Comment: Have you imported your helper functions package in the previous cell and ran it before executing the training cell?